# Spivak, Chapter 11, "Significance of Derivative": Is Theorem 7 logically correct as written?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The following Theorem appears in chapter 11, "Significance of the Derivative", of Spivak's Calculus. This chapter presents some important theorems such as the Mean Value Theorem (MVT). The following theorem is a consequence of the MVT:

> **Theorem**
>
> Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$, and that $f'(x)$ exists for all $x$
> in some interval containing $a$, except perhaps for $x=a$. Suppose,
> moreover, that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$ exists. Then $f'(a)$ also
> exists and
>
> $$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$$

This theorem has the following statements in the antecedent:

1. $f$ is continuous at $a$
2. $f'$ exists for all points in some interval containing $a$ except possible at $a$ itself
3. $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$ exists

**My question relates to coming up with two examples of functions, the second function being the important one as it illustrates the question that entitles this post.**

**First function:** What is an example of a function that satisfies 1 and 2 but not 3?

**Second Function:** 2 allows $f'$ not to exist at $a$, but the consequent (ie conclusion) of the theorem says that $f'(a)$ does exist. Can we even come up with an example of a function that satisfies 1, 2, and 3 but for which $f'$ doesn't exist at $a$?

Comment: First function: $f(x) = \vert x \vert$ on $[-1,1].$

Comment: for the second function, isn't it exactly your theorem that prevents such an example?

Comment: I agree with 311411. Makes sense after I couldn't come up with a counter-example also...

Comment: The theorem's phrasing is (from the logical point of view) a bit odd. I would write it as follows, which is the way it appears in Landau's calculus book: - - - - - - - Suppose $f$ is continuous at $a$, and that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x)$ exists. Then $f'(a)$ also
exists and 

$$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{x \to a} f'(x).$$

Comment: The "except" phrase in item 2 is not strictly part of the logic. It's just there to say "Hey! We're not going to assume that $f'(a)$ exists! But we're not assuming it doesn't exist either!! We're making no assumptions about existence of $f'(a)$ whatsoever!!!" (annoying emphasis added)

Comment: Right, I agree with Lee. It is a bit of a signpost for the reader.

Comment: @evianpring: Just one observation: Under the hypothesis given to you, and by virtue of the mean value theorem one has that $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(c_x)$ for all $x\neq a$ near $a$ and $c_x$ between $x$ and $a$. Thus, if $x\rightarrow a$, $c_x\rightarrow a$ and as $\lim_{t\rightarrow a}f'(t)=L$ exists, you have that $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a)=L$.